# What is responsible for an airplane's sound?

Tags: acoustics, aircraft

Airplanes traveling at supersonic speeds produce sonic booms because the pressure waves they create converge to produce an extra high intensity wave. But what about planes traveling at slower speeds? These create pressure waves too (although they do not converge). Are these pressure waves the sound you hear from an ordinary plane in the sky? I always thought the sound of an aircraft came from its engine noise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many contributions to an aeroplane's noise.

- engine noise.
- [aeroacoustic effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroacoustics), that is generation of sound by turbulent currents around an object.
- Vibrations of the parts of the aeroplane (caused either directly by vibrations from the engine or due to interaction with the air).

I can't give you precise numbers as to which parts of the overall noise are caused by the different factors. But they certainly all contribute to what you hear.

I think the engine noise will usually dominate, but specifics depend highly on the airspeed, the model of aircraft, etc. – see e.g. [here](https://www.airservicesaustralia.com/community/environment/aircraft-noise/monitoring-aircraft-noise/understanding-aircraft-noise/).

(And note that aeroacoustic effects have a relevant contribution to the engine noise.)

Comment: Glider planes emit almost no noise.

Comment: Yes but you *can* hear them (and one factor is that they have a relatively low airspeed).

Comment: But the difference between a glider and a small motor driven aircraft tell you what is the most important part.